# delete rows where amount or rows per group greater than value of grouped dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to delete all rows with an ID number greater than the length value.

```
Tracks <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c")
Length <- c(2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2)
ID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2)
df <- data.frame(Tracks, Length, ID)

  Tracks Length ID
1      a      2  1
2      a      2  2
3      a      2  3
4      b      1  1
5      b      1  2
6      b      1  3
7      b      1  4
8      c      2  1
9      c      2  2
```

I grouped my data using group_by of the dplyr package, print shows that the grouping was successful

```
df_group <- df %>% group_by(Tracks)
> print(df_group)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   Tracks [3]
  Tracks Length    ID
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a           2     1
2 a           2     2
3 a           2     3
4 b           1     1
5 b           1     2
6 b           1     3
7 b           1     4
8 c           2     1
9 c           2     2
```

I tried using the head function as this should give me the best results. For this I want to define n= with a function giving back the max value for Length of every group

```
df2 <- head(df_group, n = max(df$Length))
print(df2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Tracks [1]
  Tracks Length    ID
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a           2     1
2 a           2     2

group_modify(df_group, head(df_group, n = max(df$Length)), .keep = TRUE)
Error: Can't convert a `grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function
```

Seems like the head function is not working on groups as it is only returning the first two rows, I tried group_modify instead but this is not working either.

Any ideas what could be a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `slice` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  group_by(Tracks) %>% slice(seq_len(max(Length))) %>% ungroup

#  Tracks Length    ID
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a           2     1
#2 a           2     2
#3 b           1     1
#4 c           2     1
#5 c           2     2
```

Or `filter` :

```
df %>%  group_by(Tracks) %>% filter(ID <= max(Length)) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, it perfectly works with slice

Answer (score 1):

```
df_filtered <- df[df$ID <= df$Length, ]
```

This should do the job. You can always select rows and columns from a data.frame in the format `df[rows,columns]` In this case, the blank space after the comma just means "get all the columns".

Answer (score 1):

Try `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  ID <= Length
)
```

which would give

```
  Tracks Length ID
1      a      2  1
2      a      2  2
4      b      1  1
8      c      2  1
9      c      2  2
```

Comment: Very concise and without any packages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing very good solutions one could also use `which`: I am aware the logic index is part (as contributed by David) part of this answer.

```
df1 <- df[which(!ID > Length),]

output:
> df1
  Tracks Length ID
1      a      2  1
2      a      2  2
4      b      1  1
8      c      2  1
9      c      2  2
```